Why am I seeing poor encoding performance on AWS with NV_ENC for first run of app
I have cross posted on repost.aws so apologies to those who are reading this twice.
I have a windows app that interactively streams content from a directx 3D rendering over webrtc, after encoding with FFMPEG using h264_nvenc encoder, support for which I've compiled in.
The app currently starts running 2 minutes after the instance starts. It is started via a .bat file that's launched on startup, and has a timeout call in the .bat file to achieve the delay.
I'm using a g5.2xlarge, so the GPU is an A10G. I consistently get low encoding frame rates (under 10FPS) on any instance that starts up like this.
However, if I then reboot the application, encoding rates go up to the high 20s FPS.
As far as my app is concerned, it is finding the encoder ok both times. I have verified with nvidia-smi encodersessions that the encoding rate is 9FPS on first run and then jumps to around 29-30 on the second.
In all cases, nvidia-smi shows the app is using the GPU.
When using a different instance type - g4dn.2xlarge - the encoding rate is as expected from the first run of the app. This uses a T4.
I thought I had solved the problem by waiting (with a loop in the startup script that tests every 5s) until nvidia-smi returned successfully before starting my app, because if I logged into it early enough I would get a "9" return code, indicating that the driver hadn't loaded yet.
Interestingly the logging indicates that when I'm not logged into the instance (via fleet manager remote desktop), nvidia-smi returns 0 the first time it is called.
Any thoughts on what could be causing this - seems like a driver issue - and any workarounds?
EDIT:
I've since even modified my app so that with a command line option it will just encode a requested number of generated frames, and then exit. I run it with that flag four times before starting it without the flag, and I still get the same poor encoding when it starts up proper.
I've removed some extraneous detail from the post as well.

In nvidia-smi do you see a difference in the GPU performance state (P##) between the 1st and 2nd runs or does it stay at the same level?

It's at P0 for both

I also saw some issues with the A10G but probably related to the Desktop Duplication API and/or DWM. How are you capturing the frames?

Interesting!Frames are copied internally in the dx12 app, and sent to an encoder that’s compiled in to the same app

I suggest doing what I did and take a look at both ok/not ok scenarios using Nvidia Nsight Systems. You can capture a lot of events, including video encoding related, just enable them in the project configuration. If you do find something interesting please ping back :)

Good idea, will give that a whirl
